# I have only got one handle visible in the graph editor when set to bezier

Tags: animation, graph-editor

[image: Bezier graph editor 1 handle]

I can only see the bezier handle to the right of my breakdown frame in the graph editor. I've tried setting the previous keyframe to bezier as well but i still only see one handle

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by selecting all my keyframes in the graph editor and setting to bezier. (Pressing "T" in the timeline > Bezier)

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender.SE! Thanks for your contribution! Is this an answer that contributes to the solution or another question? Please try to focus as precisely as possible on the answer, and clarify questions in the comments. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, thanks! I basically solved my own question, yes sorry it's confusing because i included a question in it. I would like to mark it as the solution in 2 days time. The last part of my answer i could have included as a comment, apologies i didn't think of that but thank you for clearing it up.

Comment: No problem, no harm done. But I would still ask you to edit the answer again and describe the solution in more detail, so that others can also benefit from your contribution. Thank you!